# Pulling multiple names that are listed from a different sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have consolidated data from sheet "three". The data consists of how a person is doing in their work. The two cells to the right of the person name give me their data, and that's what I'm transferring. Now I'm trying to take that data and place them in certain cells in a different sheet. Using VBA of course.

I tried using an IF statement, but I think that might be the reason its not working

```
Sub button()

    With Worksheets("three").Range("G1")

        If .Value = "sconlon@iadvancenow.com" Then

            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C3") = .Offset(0, 1).Value
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D3") = .Offset(0, 2).Value


        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

What I'm getting from this code alone is just one person's data. I need multiple people's data taken and placed somewhere else. The real problem is some times when the data is updated that person name might not be there (because they might not have done any work), maybe someone else name pops up. who every name pops up needs to be set to their cell in a different sheet.

Comment: A simple `VLookUp`would do the trick, wouldn't it?

Comment: Looks like you  need a loop instead of an `IF`

Comment: @OmarAljonubi so you have a sheet where you have just Names or whatever, and another sheet with the names and additional data. You need to pull the data to te first sheet depending on the names?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a VLOOKUP.  If it has to be VBA, then this is a fairly simple solution for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sLookupCol As String
    Dim sLookupTable As String

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    sLookupCol = "A"
    sLookupTable = "'three'!$G:$I"

    With ws.Range("C3:D" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, sLookupCol).End(xlUp).Row)
        If .Row < 3 Then Exit Sub   'No values to lookup
        .Formula = "=VLOOKUP($" & sLookupCol & .Row & "," & sLookupTable & ",COLUMN(B1),FALSE)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I added that code to my macro and it didn't work @tigeravatar

Comment: like nothing happened when I ran it @tigeravatar

Comment: @OmarAljonubi That's probably because the lookup column isn't actually column A.  What column in `Sheet2` are the lookup values?  If they're in column B, change `sLookupCol` to `"B"`

Comment: that worked great, but all I need is how to take each persons data and place them in a different cell in a different sheet. Because I created a seating chart and each person is in a different spot so I need to place their data in their own cell @tigeravatar. Also, not be a burden, but need the data not to be in a row from but column.

Comment: @OmarAljonubi What you're describing is very different from your original question.  Please open a new question and provide sample data with expected results.